# How To Run Different, Multiple Rscripts on SGE Cluster

Tags: r, bash, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I am trying to run different Rscripts on a SGE cluster, each Rscript only changes by one variable (e.g. cancer <- "UVM" or "ACC", etc.).

I have attempted two ways: either run a Single Rscript that gets command line arguments for the 30 different cancer names

OR

run each Rscript (i.e. UVM.r, ACC.r, etc.)

Either way, I am having alot of difficulty figuring out how to submit these jobs so I can run either one Rscript 30 times with different argument each time OR run multiple Rscripts with no command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use while loop in bash for this.

1. Setup input file of arguments, e.g. `args.txt`:

   ```
   UVM
   ACC
   ```
2. Run `qsub` in `while` loop to submit script for each argument:

   ```
   while read arg
   do 
       echo "Rscript script.R ${arg}" | qsub <options>
   done <args.txt
   ```

   Above uses `echo` to pass code to run to `qsub`.

Answer (score 0):

A job script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -t 1-30
shift ${SGE_TASK_ID}
exec Rscript script.R $1
```

Submit like this `qsub job_script dummy  UVM ACC ...`